# How to read data from an html page into a cell?

Tags: html, matlab

I have to manually populate a spreadsheet of many webpages. I only have to pick up some details from every page such as its title, description, etc.. Doing this manually is becoming too monotonous and boring so I thought I could semi-automate it using Matlab.

Suppose this is the page as an example: http://www.smythstoys.com/uk/en-gb/video-games-tablets/c-751/xbox-one/p-14141/xbox-one-1tb-console/

I can read this page into matlab using:

```
page = urlread('..the_webpage..');
```

This basically copies its source code into a string variable. Viewing the source I can see that the Title is in its `<title></title>` tag and so is the description.

Is there any way I can extract these values from the string and into cell arrays. From there I can then move them easily to an excel spreadsheet. I tried using `textscan` but it did not work as I cannot tell the delimiter between the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write a HTML parser in Matlab. Don't. There's a lot of projects that do that, because it's a very common task, but also a very very complex one.

Try python, and beautifulsoup, and write a python program that extracts the data for your matlab application. You can execute the python program from matlab, then.

Matlab is a mathematical processing language. Writing a HTML parser would be like [cutting down a tree with a herring](https://youtu.be/QTQfGd3G6dg?t=4m28s). Don't waste your PhD candidate's life with that. Learn a minimal bit of python and do general purpose problems with a general purpose language.

Comment: On a sidenote: I looked into the StackOverflow user that went insane and it does mention that you can in fact use REGEX on something that you know the format of and on a limited basis. So in this case grabbing stupid info like the title or other stuff of that nature would actually be doable. Even though it isn't the "best" idea.

Comment: Exactly!  Don't use Matlab for this.  Use Python, R, or Excel.